# How to use papertrail with Lumen

Tags: laravel, logging, lumen, forge

I am learning to use Forge with my Laravel and Lumen apps. Forge easily integrates with papertrail. All you have to do is add `APP_LOG=syslog` to the `.env` file, and give an address, like `logs.papertrailapp.com:11111`, in the papertrail section of the Forge website.

This works well, but only with Laravel, and not Lumen. What can I do to make my Lumen apps work with papertrail?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact code that works for me:

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
   $syslog = new \Monolog\Handler\SyslogHandler('lumen');
   $formatter = new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null, null, false, true);
   $syslog->setFormatter($formatter);
   $monolog->pushHandler($syslog);
   return $monolog;
});
```

Placed in `bootstrap/app.php` underneath the `\\ $app->withFacades();`